# How can I get rid of recyclerview item's click when I click on an imageview inside it?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Currently I set Imageview click even in ViewHolder class like this:

```
public class HomeMenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnClickListener {

        public ImageView imageView;
        String[] tagBackgroundColors;
        String[] tagBorderColors;

        public HomeMenuViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType) {
            super(itemView);
            this.viewType = viewType;

            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_menu);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickListener.onClick(getAdapterPosition(), false);
            int id = v.getId();
            if (id == R.id.cb_share_dday_show) {
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;
                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    mPref.setShareDdayShow(Cons.TRUE);
                } else {
                    mPref.setShareDdayShow(Cons.FALSE);
                }
                menuCallback.refreshFragments();
            } else if (id == R.id.img_menu) {
                showChangeColorDialog();
            }
        }


    private void showChangeColorDialog() {
            Dialog gridViewDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
            gridViewDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_change_color);
            // You have to create the GridView object with gridViewDialog
            GridView gv = ((GridView) gridViewDialog.findViewById(R.id.grid_change_color));
            ChangeTagIconAdapter adapter = new ChangeTagIconAdapter(mContext, tagBackgroundColors, tagBorderColors);
            gv.setAdapter(adapter);
            gridViewDialog.show();

        }
}
```

I put the recyclerview inside a navigation drawer, the function of recyclerview's item is closing the drawer. What I want is when I click on the imageview inside recyclerview's items, a dialog should appear without closing the drawer but I always get click even of both recyclerview's item and the imageview inside it. Please tell me how to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: Inside onClick you check if Checkbox is checked, but where does reference of this CheckBox is into your Adapter ?

Comment: @Gorio I'm asking about the ImageView, not Checkbox, so I removed some unneccessary code.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, could you share complete code to try help you ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I should set click listener in adapter instead of in viewholder. Now it works ;)